# How do I remove list bullets?

Tags: wordpress, css

I am am having trouble removing list bullets on my on line resume.  I have tried the following :

```
.nobull {
  list-style: none; 
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

And clearing my browser cache. [Here in a link to the resume.](http://smithdesign.us/tims-resume/)

Comment: Does your list (`ul` or `ol`), or the child `li` elements have the relevant `class` name?

Comment: You have quite a lot CSS references in your code that spit out 404 HTML instead of CSS. You should fix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to set the property on your `p` tags, you'll want to either eplicitly set the class on the `ul` elements, or embed your `ul` elements inside the `p` tag (which I think is invalid markup, but I could be wrong there).

```
ul.no-bull,
.no-bull ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
```

Alternatively you could adopt an "opt-in" approach to bullet points, which is what most tend to do; this saves you from having to add `no-bull` to each `ul`. Something like this:

```
ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.has-bullets
{
    list-style: none outside disc;
    margin-left: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
  list-style-type:none !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` is not a solution, it's a curse.

Answer (score 0):

Just `list-style: none;` works, but I don't see where you use the class `.nobull`